# Cannot create stream with KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

**I am trying to create a stream using ksql.**

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM fakeData22 (Id VARCHAR, category VARCHAR, timeStamp VARCHAR, deviceID INTEGER, properties MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='fake-data-19', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

**I get the following output. Am i missing something?**

```
line 1:94: extraneous input 'properties' expecting {'ADD', 'APPROXIMATE', 'AT', 'CONFIDENCE', 'NO', 'SUBSTRING', 'POSITION', 'TINYINT', 'SMALLINT', 'INTEGER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'INTERVAL', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE', 'SECOND', 'ZONE', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'ROW', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'GRANT', 'REVOKE', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PUBLIC', 'OPTION', 'EXPLAIN', 'ANALYZE', 'FORMAT', 'TYPE', 'TEXT', 'GRAPHVIZ', 'LOGICAL', 'DISTRIBUTED', 'TRY', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'SCHEMAS', 'CATALOGS', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'TO', 'SYSTEM', 'BERNOULLI', 'POISSONIZED', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'RESCALED', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'SESSION', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'WORK', 'ISOLATION', 'LEVEL', 'SERIALIZABLE', 'REPEATABLE', 'COMMITTED', 'UNCOMMITTED', 'READ', 'WRITE', 'ONLY', 'CALL', 'NFD', 'NFC', 'NFKD', 'NFKC', 'IF', 'NULLIF', 'COALESCE', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}
Caused by: line 1:94: extraneous input 'properties' expecting {'ADD', 'APPROXIMATE', 'AT', 'CONFIDENCE', 'NO', 'SUBSTRING', 'POSITION', 'TINYINT', 'SMALLINT', 'INTEGER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'INTERVAL', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE', 'SECOND', 'ZONE', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'ROW', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'GRANT', 'REVOKE', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PUBLIC', 'OPTION', 'EXPLAIN', 'ANALYZE', 'FORMAT', 'TYPE', 'TEXT', 'GRAPHVIZ', 'LOGICAL', 'DISTRIBUTED', 'TRY', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'SCHEMAS', 'CATALOGS', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'TO', 'SYSTEM', 'BERNOULLI', 'POISSONIZED', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'RESCALED', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'SESSION', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'WORK', 'ISOLATION', 'LEVEL', 'SERIALIZABLE', 'REPEATABLE', 'COMMITTED', 'UNCOMMITTED', 'READ', 'WRITE', 'ONLY', 'CALL', 'NFD', 'NFC', 'NFKD', 'NFKC', 'IF', 'NULLIF', 'COALESCE', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}
```

Comment: After having fixed the problem of not creating the stream, when i query the stream the properties are always null when they should not be.
1529319092196 | null | id14568 | fan | Mon Jun 18 12:51:32 CEST 2018 | 15 | null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `properties` must be a reserved word in KSQL. I've added this to [an issue on the KSQL project](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1212) for us to track, but in the meantime please try enclosing `properties` in backticks:

```
CREATE STREAM fakeData22 \
      (Id VARCHAR, category VARCHAR, timeStamp VARCHAR, deviceID INTEGER, \
      `properties` MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) \
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='fake-data-19', \
      VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding backticks solves the problem. Now I am facing another problem. Whenever i query the stream, the properties are always null when they should be. The other fields like category or timeStamp are ok. Am i missing something here too?

Comment: Hmmm it sounds like maybe KSQL is treating the backticks as literal components of the column name (i.e. is looking for a field in your data called `\`properties\``). Can you try using double-quotes instead? And do you have the option of changing the field name in your source data (lame, I know, but useful to rule out the problem here)?

Comment: I have changed the field name to deviceProperties and the problem still persists. Is it possible that KSQL cannot query on a nested field?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the JSON data? I can then replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because KSQL doesn't support backtick escaping.
The actually working workaround if table columns are declared with backtick escaping and being **uppercase** :

```
CREATE STREAM fakeData22 \
    (Id VARCHAR, category VARCHAR, timeStamp VARCHAR, deviceID INTEGER, \
    `PROPERTIES` MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) \
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='fake-data-19', \
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

and query like below.

```
ksql> select `PROPERTIES` from fakeData22;
```

Related KSQL Github issue : [Support escaping identifier names. #677](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/677)